# How to ignore missing data in form of dots?

Tags: r, missing-data

this probably a very simple question but I am a very beginner in R programming so far.
I have a data set of annual GDP growth rate for all African countries (54) in the period 1960-2020. There are missing data for some years and some countries but not in form of NA as usual but in form of dots ("..."). Of course, this makes all further calculations impossible.
How could I either "clean" the data set from those missing values or maybe replace them by zero ("O)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
#load an example dataset
data(iris)

#set cells row2/column3 and row3/column2 to "..."
iris[2,3] <- "..."
iris[3,2] <- "..."

# View the data which has now the same problem as yours
iris

#Solution, replace all "..." with NAs
iris[iris == "..."] <- NA
```

Of course you can also write 0 instead of NA for your replacements.